# Is there a wait to have selenium driver get url return early in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working with selenium ChromeDriver in Python for some webscraping tasks. I noticed that sometimes the `driver.get(url)` calls were taking a long time to return despite most of the page being loaded (everything but the ads).

I tried fixing it by setting a small page_load_timeout, but I don't like that option since picking a number would be arbitrary. Too long and my program takes forever, and too short and maybe the elements I care about won't be available.

Is there a way I can make `driver.get(url)` return as soon as an element is clickable, or should I simply set a miniature page_load_timeout and rely on `WebDriverWait` to wait until the elements I care about are clickable? Like below:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),
                                           options=self._options)
self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(0)
try:
    self.driver.get(url)
except (Timeout Exception):
    pass
WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout=30).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, val))).click()
```

I'm hoping for a cleaner solution like:

`driver.get(url, WebDriverWait(EC.element_to_be_clickable((element))`

Comment: you don't really want page load to timeout as you won't be able to do anything but use another .get() if it does.  You can, however, set a pageLoadStrategy:  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#pageloadstrategy   It sounds like you want "eager".  If you set it to "none" you'll rely completely on webdriverwaits to do their job.  (and DOM may still be changing which can lead to troubles with stale elements...)

Comment: My god that is absolutely perfect! Thank you so much! Feel free to put that as an answer so I can checkmark it for others who have the same question. I'm SO excited, it worked PERFECTLY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't really want page load to timeout as you won't be able to do anything but use another .get() if it does. You can, however, set a pageLoadStrategy: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#pageloadstrategy … It sounds like you want "eager". If you set it to "none" you'll rely completely on webdriverwaits to do their job. (and DOM may still be changing which can lead to troubles with stale elements...)